# Trusted domain navigation does not work inside iframe

Tags: office-js

Inside Office add-in - Word add-in for instance - It does not open in add-in itself when you click links (<a/>) inside an iframe that loads content from a different site (domain). Add-in's manifest file has <AppDomains/> correctly configured. It is working if links are not in iframe. Is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design, we don's support cross-domain pages for security reasons. If you need to do that you need to use our dialog API to pop a dialog with it.